Trying to return a list of values from a nested dictionary within another dictionary
This is my dictionary, the first set is specific to the server, the 'regd' key is able to fit multiple or many users.
{
    "0": {
        "server": 681262466650734596,
        "channel": 693639674841006101,
        "balance": 1000,
        "bal2": 30000,
        "regd": [
            {
                "user": 624748908479905812,
                "exp": 10,
                "rank": 1,
                "points": 1,
                "msgs": 1,
                "tokens": 10000
            },
            {
                "user": 1096531392369807492,
                "exp": 10,
                "rank": 1,
                "points": 1,
                "msgs": 1,
                "tokens": 10000
            }
        ]
    }
}

Notice the "user" keys, the values for the two "user" keys are different, so I am writing a function that will include the "user" number when called, then with the given user number, compare with other 2 user numbers, if a match is found return the rest of the values corresponding with the matching user numbers.
So in summary, call a function with the user number: 624748908479905812 and server number: 681262466650734596, that function should read the whole dictionary, iterate through the one key in search of a matching server number, when found, iterate through the nested dicts within the "regd" key, search for a matching user number with the given user number and then return the data if and only if the server numbers match and the user numbers match. It should only return the dictionary with the corresponding key, not both.
This is the function I have now to check the data:
def StatsBlyatX(self, User: bool, Server: bool):
        gop = self.ReadLevel()
        for key, value_key in gop.items():
            if value_key['server'] == Server:
                rlist = value_key['regd']
                try:
                    g = [gop[i]['server'] for i in gop if gop[i]['server'] == Server]
                    ch = [gop[i]['channel'] for i in gop if gop[i]['server'] == Server]
                    b1 = [gop[i]['balance'] for i in gop if gop[i]['server'] == Server]
                    b2 = [gop[i]['bal2'] for i in gop if gop[i]['server'] == Server]

                    for entry in rlist:
                        if entry['user'] == User:
                            msgs = entry['msgs']
                            tokens = entry['tokens']
                            exp = entry['exp']
                            user = entry['user']
                            rank = entry['rank']
                            points = entry['points']
                            FS = (g, ch, b1, b2, msgs, tokens, exp, user, rank, points)
                            print(FS)
                            print("stats got")
                            return #FS
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    return None

But it returns None when I want it to return one of the two "regd" dictionaries

If you intend to pass in User as 624748908479905812 then is the type flag bool really what you want?

I guess so, is the bool causing problems?

No, type hints are just informational.

But what's the point of providing a type hint that you know is wrong? It will confuse users and cause you to get warnings when you run a type checker.

What do the keys (like "0") of the top-level dictionary represent? A dictionary whose keys are sequential numbers should probably be a list.

If you iterate the servers then you can find those one(s) you are interested in. Once you have one, you can save the important values in a list. Then for each interesting server you can find interesting users and save their values in a list. Then for each you return a list (or tuple) of the user values list concatenated to the server values list.
For illustration, something like this might do it.
import json

gop = {
    "0": {
        "server": 681262466650734596,
        "channel": 693639674841006101,
        "balance": 1000,
        "bal2": 30000,
        "regd": [
            {
                "user": 624748908479905812,
                "exp": 10,
                "rank": 1,
                "points": 1,
                "msgs": 1,
                "tokens": 10000
            },
            {
                "user": 1096531392369807492,
                "exp": 10,
                "rank": 1,
                "points": 1,
                "msgs": 1,
                "tokens": 10000
            }
        ]
    }
}
user_id = 624748908479905812 
server_id = 681262466650734596

for server in gop.values():
    if server["server"] != server_id:
        continue

    server_values = [v for k, v in server.items() if k != "regd"]
    for user in server["regd"]:
        if user["user"] == user_id:
            user_values = [v for v in user.values()]
            print(server_values + user_values)

That should give you:
[681262466650734596, 693639674841006101, 1000, 30000, 624748908479905812, 10, 1, 1, 1, 10000]

As your method, try something like:
def StatsBlyatX(self, user_id: int, server_id: int):
    gop = self.ReadLevel()
    results = []
    for server in gop.values():
        if server["server"] != server_id:
            continue
        server_values = [v for k, v in server.items() if k != "regd"]
        for user in server["regd"]:
            if user["user"] == user_id:
                user_values = [v for v in user.values()]
                results.append(server_values + user_values)
    return results

I might also look at leveraging yield rather than building and returning the list.
